# A maximization problem, with motivation in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Consider the [minimization problem described this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.01336). Let $f_{\lambda}$ be the minimizer. As a part of extending my work, I am able to show the following facts

$$\lim_\limits{\lambda \to 0}\|f_{\lambda}\|_{L^2} = 0$$ and $$\lim_\limits{\lambda \to \infty}\|f_{\lambda}\|_{L^2} = 0$$

My problem now is (as I would like to extend my work), find $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$ for which $\|f_{\lambda}\|_{L^2}$ is maximum. Appreciate your suggestions to solve this problem.

---

The minimization problem from the linked paper is given below for the self containment of the post. If given that $k>\frac{m}{2}$, the paper proves that there is a unique minimizer for the functional $C(f)$ in the set $S$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is given that $k>\frac{m}{2}$

---

### My progress

**Partial Progress** :

Progress : I am able to derive the corresponding PDE equations for the problem.

Let $f(\lambda,x) = f_{\lambda}(x)$. Then

[image]

The first equation corresponds to maximizing $\|f_{\lambda}\|$, while the second PDE is for the minimization problem associated with the parameter $\lambda$.

The second equation (minimization problem), given any $\lambda$, I can solve for $f(\lambda,.)$ either using linear algebra or steepest descent algorithm, which I have described in my article. Now I need to use this solution and the first equation to obtain $\lambda$, which is a problem I am facing.

Trying to solve using linear algebra, by formulating the discrete version of the problem using Fourier series coefficients and Plancheral theorem, I get stuck at [the matrix problem described here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/330020/14414).

---

**More Partial Progress**

An Iterative algorithm which is a modified steepest descent.

> 1. Initialize $f$.
> 2. Assuming some $\lambda$ and assuming gradient of $C_{\lambda}(f)$ wrt $f$ be $\nabla_f C_{\lambda}(f)$, and if we were to update $f$
>    with this gradient as in we do in steepest descent, it would be
>    $f^u_\lambda = f - \delta \nabla_f C_{\lambda}(f)$, where $\delta$ is
>    a constant learning rate. Now set
>    $\frac{\partial\|f^u_\lambda\|}{\partial \lambda} = 0$ and solve for
>    $\lambda$. Let the root be $\lambda_0$.
> 3. Update $f = f^u_{\lambda_0}$. (update $f$ as in steepest descent, but using $\lambda$ value as $\lambda_0$ which was computed in step
>    2.)
> 4. check some convergence criterion and if not met, go to step 2.

I have implemented this numerically and it converges as desired. Need to work on the proof.

PS : This was first posted on MO by me, 3 months back. [Link](https://mathoverflow.net/q/332439/1441) and cross posted on math.SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3306993/2987).